# How do you move a bone in the Blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine

In Blender I can move the pose of an object using:

```
bpy.data.objects["Rig"].pose.bones["Bone"].location[0] += 0.1
```

In fact, if I execute this code in the game engine, it does nothing in the game engine, but when I come back to blender the object's pose has moved as expected.

How do I achieve the same thing in the game engine? I want to move some eyes based on a simple keyboard input.

**Update:**

I have found that I can access, but not update, this value in the game engine with:

```
import bge
channel = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.channels["Bone"]
print(channel.location)

Console output:
<Vector (1.1683, -0.0078, 0.0000)>
```

Trying to update that value with `channel.location.x += 0.1` does nothing in-game though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an update call: `armature.update()`

More precisely, `bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.update()` needs to be called after any updates to the armature in order for it to update in the game engine.