# Blender Game. My Game does not move when executing but it goes to the final position when I stop it

Tags: python, game-engine, pose-mode

I'm trying to create a simulation in blender of a person walking.

I did a program to advance one leg 1 degree (and return the other 1 deg) after pressing the space bar but I can't see the advance while the game is executing and instead of that, I see the movement until I stop the game. I think it could be because of the pose mode. But I'm not sure. No error is displayed in the console while executing.

I attach some pictures and the code:

1. Before running the game:
   [image: 1. Before running the game:]
2. While running the game nothing moves.
   [image: 2. While running the game nothing moves.]
3. When I stop it after pressing the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> a few times and it leaves the executing screen it appears it what I think is the final position, but nothing happens while executing.
   [image]
4. Logic Editor:
   [image]
5. Code:

```
    import math
    import bpy
    import numpy as np
    import bge
    from bge import logic

    controller = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = controller.owner
    
    sensors=own.sensors

    #CODE PART 1. ROTATION
    ob = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    rhip = ob.pose.bones['Thigh.R']
    rleg = ob.pose.bones['Leg.R']
    rfoot= ob.pose.bones['Foot.R']
    
    lhip = ob.pose.bones['Thigh.L']
    lleg = ob.pose.bones['Leg.L']
    lfoot= ob.pose.bones['Foot.L']
    
    # Set rotation mode to Euler XYZ, easier to understand
    # than default quaternions
    rhip.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    rleg.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    rfoot.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    lhip.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    lleg.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    lfoot.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    
    # select axis in ['X','Y','Z']  <--bone local
    axis = 'Z'
    actual_angle = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    def refresh_angle():
        global actual_angle
        lecture=[1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
        angle=np.array(lecture)-np.array(actual_angle)
        
        rhip.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[0]))
        rleg.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[1]))
        rfoot.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[2]))
        lhip.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[3]))
        lleg.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[4]))
        lfoot.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle[5]))
        
        actual_angle=angle
    
    
    if sensors["Spacebar"].positive:
         refresh_angle()
```

Comment: BPY doesn`t work with BGE, [bge armature](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.html?highlight=armature%20update#bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.update), related [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92722/how-do-you-move-a-bone-in-the-blender-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92722/how-do-you-move-a-bone-in-the-blender-game-engine)

Comment: How did you solve it? Where do you specify the name of the bone? in owner.update??   `import bge channel = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.channels["Bone"]` `bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.update() print(channel.location)`

Comment: Did you need to change something in the Logic Editor??

Answer (score 1):

While in the related question i test `channel.location.x += 0.1` and `channel.location.x += 0.1` but none work all time print (0,0,0) (i try because i never has move a bone), so i read the [armature](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.html?highlight=armature%20update#bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.update) documentation and [location](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.BL_ArmatureChannel.html#bge.types.BL_ArmatureChannel.location). Finally end up with this script.

```
from bge import logic

armature = logic.getCurrentController().owner
if not hasattr(logic, 'boneLocation'):
    logic.boneLocation = 0
else:
    logic.boneLocation += 0.5
    channel = armature.channels["moveBone.003"]
    channel.location = [logic.boneLocation, 0, 1]
    print(channel.location)
    logic.getCurrentController().owner.update()
```

`Blender Game Engine Started
<Vector (0.5000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.5000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (2.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (2.5000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (3.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (3.5000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (4.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>`

Comment: Thank you very much. The above code its just working for me for translation and not rotation; it doesn't move the full chain of bones like if it where in pose mode. Did you know one way to move one bone by rotation in some quantity of degrees with implicit movement of the full chain of bones?. Reading [Armature](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.BL_ArmatureChannel.html#bge.types.BL_ArmatureChannel.location) I think joint_rotation could work, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: I would like to help you while i learn how to do it but i am really busy and that may need a lot of time. Also i don't have a single minimum armature to start testing. I made the above just with one bone